# Error creating GlobalAddress: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.networks.use' permission for 'projects

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I'm getting the below error while creating the private service connection using terraform, can someone help
and also i've provided network admin permission to the service account

```
Error creating GlobalAddress: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.networks.use' permission for 'projects/alpine-bond-338506/global/networks/testvpc', forbidden
│
│   with module.vpc.google_compute_global_address.private_ip_address,
│   on modules/vpc/main.tf line 181, in resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address":
│  181: resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_address" {
```

Comment: 1) Show your Terraform code. 2) Double-check the service account that you are using with Terraform and the IAM roles assigned to the service account. 3) Edit your question with details.